# Drupal - editing tab options for a content type not showing up

Tags: drupal, menu, tabs, admin, revisions

I'm working on a D5 site and a lot of the content types have the menus at the top of the  edit page.

Examples:

Overview | Grants | Dev load | Dev render | Edit | Revisions | Track | Workflow

Overview | Dev load | Dev render | Edit | Revisions | Track | Workflow | Node queue | RelatedContent

I'm not sure where these tabs come from, but I need to enable the menu for a content type that doesn't have them visible.

I checked the workflow setting and the content type in question was specified to use workflow. So there should be at least another tab in addition to edit.

The end goal is to have revisions show up in the menu, but I need to get the menu showing first.

Any ideas where to start looking?

Answer (score 0):

As for where the tabs come from, you could (re)read [my answer to your similar question from a few month ago](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1609625/drupal-tabs-not-including-edit-revisions-workflow/1610278#1610278), but that was geared at a programming perspective, while this sounds more like an administrative problem.

The most common reason for a tab not showing up is that the current user does not have the right to use the functionality the tab offers - you should check your permission settings, especially if the site in question uses one or more specific access modules.

Another possibility is that the function the tab offers is not enabled for the content type in question, e.g. if 'use revisions' is not enabled for a content type, the tab won't show up (and IIRC, it only shows if there are already revisions available for that node, so if a node has not been edited yet, no tab is displayed)

A third place to check would be the page.tpl.php file(s). The tabs are available there as the $tabs variable and usually printed somewhere at the top of the content region. If your site uses multiple page template files for different situations, it might be that one of those simply doesn't print the $tabs variable.

A forth possibility would be a `xyz_preprocess_page()` function within a custom module or theme that explicitly clears/overwrites the $tabs variable for some special circumstances.

Comment: I am running as admin user and have all the proper permissions and the tabs not showing up for me in the admin. Make a new revision is checked for the content type as well as the particular instance of the ContentType I am looking at. I did a search for "preprocess_page" in the sourcecode and there are no function calls.  Any other ideas?

Comment: Have you checked that there *exist* at least one revision for the particular instance you're looking at? (The revisions tab won't show until at least one prior revision has been created.) Also, have you checked for alternate page.tpl.php files? Besides this, I'm out of ideas :/